# emberjs-RC2- how to access router instance from controller & actions don't bubble to router

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In the router I have an event 'removeComment'. In the controller if access it via **this.get('target').send('removeComment', context)**;, I get the error **Nothing handled the event 'removeComment'**. When I use **this.get('target.router').send('removeComment', comment)**, the error becomes **Object # has no method 'send'**. using **this.router.send('removeComment', comment)**, will give the error: **Cannot read property 'send' of undefined**.

Also just sending the 'removeComment' action to the the PostEditController does not bubble through the controller, up to the route.

How do I access the router instance from the controller in the emberjs rc2 and routerV2.

The **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrR2T/6/)**

The Router:

```
 EmBlog.Router.map(function() {
   this.resource("posts", {path: '/posts'}, function(){
     this.route('new');

     this.resource('post', {path: '/:post_id/'}, function(){
       this.route('edit', {path: '/edit'});

       this.route('comments', {path:  '/comments'});
       this.route('newComment');
       this.route('comment', {path: '/comments/:comment_id'});    
       this.route('editComment', {path: '/comments/:comment_id/edit'});

     });    
 });
});
```

The controller

```
 EmBlog.PostEditCommentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   destroyMe: function(comment) {
     this.get('target.router').send('removeComment', comment);
   } 
});
```

The Router

```
EmBlog.PostEditCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   events: { 
      removeComment: function(context) {
       var comment = context.get('content');
       comment.deleteRecord();
       comment.get('store').commit();
       this.transitionTo('post.index');
     }          
    }
});
```

I am accessing it in the post/comments template. This is the controller for that template .

```
EmBlog.PostCommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['postEditComment']
});
```

The post/comments template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/comments">
     {{#each controller}}

     <p><a href='#' {{action destroyMe this target="controller.controllers.postEditComment"}}> Destroy </a></p>

    {{/each}}

 </script>
```

Comment: Could you add your routing map please ? I think this.get('target').send('removeComment', context)` should definitely work, but I suspect this is sent to an other route.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have added the router at the top of the question and decided to also add a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrR2T/6/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks foir the updae, end the fiddle, it helps a lot :). I think I figured out what's happening here.

First of all, the destroyMe function in the controller is not right, it should really be

```
destroyMe: function(comment) {
  this.get('target').send('removeComment', comment);
}
```

Then, you are calling it in the template of the post.comments, but you're implementing it in the 'PostEditCommentRoute', which is a subroute of PostCommentsRoute. So pulling up the event in the PostCommentsRoute should make it work.

Now, as a overall comment about your code, there are some weird things, such as

```
<p>{{#linkTo 'post.comments'}}  comments{{/linkTo}}</p>  

{{render 'post.comments' comments}}
```

As a result, when you click on the 'comments' link, it throws an error (view is already rendered).

There are also some code in the routes which could be avoid, for example all the setupController hooks like

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
  controller.set('content', model);
}
```

which is the default behavior, so you don't have to override it.

Comment: Thanks sly7_7 for all the feedback. I have deleted the setupController where they stick with the default. for the comment code causing view is already rendered, I have deleted the bit using the #render helper. I was testing both, and must have mistakenly left one uncommented out. You are right, moving  removeComment up to the PostCommentsRoute, makes the event to be called but now it gives the **new error: Cannot call method 'deleteRecord' of undefined**. I am investigating why. the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrR2T/14/)**. If I resolve it, I'll update you. **Thanks for the guidance**.

Comment: I have looked up the 'removeComment' event in the console using the debugger. The problem is with this line: **var comment = context.get('content')**. In the console if I type **comment** it is undefined. But when I type **context**, I get the right object that I want to destroy but it is not being assigned to the comment variable.

Comment: Yeah, I think the context refers to the object you are passing to the send method, so it's the comment itself. you should be able to call deleteRecord on it.

Comment: Thanks for the kind gesture and for the time you spent helping me to resolve this. It seems sometimes to resolve an issue, there is a need to take off the debugger statement. Enjoy your day. Cheers

Comment: Glad to help :) I hope you will be keep going on Ember.js :)